# Lookup Type Column in LWC Datatable dropdown hidden

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I have custom Datatable to show the lookup lightning-record-edit-form input field as column type, however, the dropdown is going to be hidden, is there a way to bring it onto the cell?

**extendedDatatableLwc.html**

```
<template>
    
</template>
```

**extendedDatatableLwc.js**

```
import lookupColumnType from "./lookupColumType.html";
import LightningDatatable from "lightning/datatable";

export default class ExtendedDatatableLwc extends LightningDatatable {
  static customTypes = {
    lookupColumn: {
      template: lookupColumnType,
      standardCellLayout: true
    }
  };
}
```

**lookupColumnType.html**

```
<template>
    <c-extended-table-lookup-column></c-extended-table-lookup-column>
</template>
```

**extendedTableLookupColumn**

```
<template>
    <div class="lookupSection" id="lookup">
        <div tabindex="0" class="container">
            <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Contact">
                <lightning-input-field class="slds-popover slds-popover_edit slds-popover__body" field-name="AccountId"
                    value={value} variant='label-hidden' data-id="input">
                </lightning-input-field>
            </lightning-record-edit-form>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**Issue:**

[image]